# Eclipse + Maven: force Execution Environment "JavaSE-1.6" instead of fixed JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, maven

I'm using Eclipse as IDE and Maven outside of it to keep all dependencies up to date and update the Eclipse-project as such. In Eclipse I usually specify the JRE system library as an execution environment for any Java-project, usually "JavaSE-1.6".

In the pom.xml I use the following lines:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <projectNameTemplate>[groupId].[artifactId]</projectNameTemplate>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This seems to let Maven pick a JDK matching 1.6. It assigns its system libraries to the classpath of the project. However, it uses jdk1.6.20 directly rather than JavaSE-1.6.

Is there a way to make Maven use JavaSE-1.6 instead?

---

EDIT:
Here's the batch file that I use to run Maven:

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Programme\java\jdk1.6.0_20
SET MAVEN_HOME=C:\Programme\apache-maven-2.2.1
SET MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
SET PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

SET EXTRA_MVN_OPTS=-Dmaven.test.skip=true

CD /D "%~dp0"
cmd /c mvn %EXTRA_MVN_OPTS% eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
cmd /c mvn %EXTRA_MVN_OPTS% clean install
```

Comment: I added the batch file for Maven and the pom.xml-lines for the `maven-eclipse-plugin`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it by setting a classpath container.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <classpathContainers>
           <classpathContainer>
    org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6
           </classpathContainer>
        </classpathContainers>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Reference:**

- [`eclipse:eclipse` Mojo >
  classpathContainers](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html#classpathContainers)

Comment: I know it does, a former client company of mine used this for years. However, the problem is that the property is marked as internal and hence subject to change

Comment: Yep, it works. If it stops working I'll open another question ;) _Sorry for the delay, but I was sick_

Comment: Can you add a note with the XPATH location of where in the pom.xml that fragment should go?!

Comment: @EdRandall don't know about XPath, but in the `<build><plugins>` section

Answer (score 2):

Go into Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments

Select JavaSE-1.6, click the checkbox on the right that should indicate "perfect match"

then use "update project configuration" from the maven menu.

Comment: It already does. Other than that I'm not allowed to use the Maven-menu as it occasionally destroys the project settings.

Comment: Which version of the maven extension are you using?  More recent versions have been VERY good about that.  If you're committing the .project & .classpath files to version control, probably not a good idea as eclipse+maven can update/reconfigure those based on dependencies and plugins.

Comment: I just saw your edit and I would look at @Sean Patric Floyd's recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `maven` and `eclipse`, perhaps you should use [M2Eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin.  The maven project (built by maven by setting `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23`) imported in Eclipse, shows up with `JRE System Library` as `JavaSE-1.6`

Comment: It would be nice to know why you would generally prefer M2Eclipse, in addition to "it works for me" for this question.