# How to set default Maven's Java in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e, maven-archetype

If I create new `Maven` project in `Eclipse` and base it on quickstart archetype, it appears with `J2SE-1.5` in `Java Build Path` window and 1.5 in `Java Compiler / JDK Compliance` window.

So, I usually have to change this to other Java manually.

Where are these default setting come from?

How to change to 1.6 or 1.7?

Answer (score 8):

The m2eclipse plugin uses the settings from the POM. So you need to add this to your POM:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.6</source>
    <target>1.6</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) has the version 3.1 in the meantime.

Comment: My mistake ;) ... Fixed!

Comment: Maven newbie here: I have put this in my pom.xml file, and chosen "update project" from the maven menu when I right click on the project, but nothing has changed.  Is there something else I have to do to get eclipse to update the java version it's using for my project?

Answer (score 2):

You should add plugin in your pom.xml like  below :

```
 <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>your version</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
         <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

And then you can see your project marked with error.In this case,
   Right click your project directory->Maven->Update Project option  will work

Comment: Only the configuration part is necessary.

Comment: Maven->Update Project was necessary for me.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to manually update the *pom.xml* with the following plugin because 1.5 is the default.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.8</version>
<configuration>
    <classpathContainers>
       <classpathContainer>
org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6
       </classpathContainer>
    </classpathContainers>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Refrences:

1. [Eclipse JRE System Library [J2SE-1.5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926798/eclipse-jre-system-library-j2se-1-5)
2. [Eclipse + Maven: force Execution Environment "JavaSE-1.6" instead of fixed JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759242/eclipse-maven-force-execution-environment-javase-1-6-instead-of-fixed-jdk)

Comment: Only the configuration of the maven-compiler-plugin is needed. Apart from that it will set the launcher within Eclipse but not the compiler which is used by maven or to be more accurate which compatibility is used of the installed jdk.