# Why maven prevent me from choosing my "Workspace Default JRE" in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

Every time I run "Maven update" on my project, maven forced JRE System Library to the `Execution Environment` option. Shown below:

[image]

How to make M2E allow me to choose the other 2 options?

I had below configuration in my pom.xml in order to [override the default J2SE-1.5 version of M2E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096608/how-to-set-default-mavens-java-in-eclipse):

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759242/eclipse-maven-force-execution-environment-javase-1-6-instead-of-fixed-jdk

Comment: @user648026 Thanks but the answer to that question uses an internal property to fix it. It's more like a workaround to me rather than a solution.